# OR condition in dynamoDB query

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I want to query the dynamoDB table based on the column status_code. I'm getting the output by using the following code:

```
params = {
    TableName : "Orders_" + environment,
    IndexName: "StatusCode-StoreID-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "StatusCode = :status_code",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":status_code": "ST01"
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    Limit : ordersPageSize
  };
```

Here I'm passing the status_code as ST01. My problem is about passing multiple values instead of ST01.
How to fetch the records with status_code value as ST01 or ST02 or ST03?

Answer (score 0):

As per [DynamoDB Query Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestSyntax)

> Valid comparisons for the sort key condition are as follows:
>
> - sortKeyName = :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is equal to :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName < :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is less than :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName <= :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is less than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName > :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is greater than :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName >= :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - sortKeyName BETWEEN :sortkeyval1 AND :sortkeyval2 - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval1, and less than
>   or equal to :sortkeyval2.
> - begins_with ( sortKeyName, :sortkeyval ) - true if the sort key value begins with a particular operand. (You cannot use this function
>   with a sort key that is of type Number.)
>
> **Note** that the function name begins_with is case-sensitive.

So, only **AND** supported for ranges. **There is no IN**. Also you could try using **begins_with**.

Your Scenario Can be converted to following Code :

```
params = {
    TableName : "Orders_" + environment,
    IndexName: "StatusCode-StoreID-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "begins_with(StatusCode, :status_code)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":status_code": "ST0"
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    Limit : ordersPageSize
};
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But this will give anything which starts with ST0. I need only ST01,ST02 and ST03.

Comment: @PETER, You may use individual 3 queries with ST01,ST02 and ST03, & then merge them. Otherwise Sorry, Dynamodb doesn't support feature like IN Query, So you can't search data like that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **`IN`** operator on `FilterExpression`.

```
params = {
    TableName : "Orders_" + environment,
    IndexName: "StatusCode-StoreID-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "StatusCode = :status_code1",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":status_code1": "ST01"
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    Limit : ordersPageSize
  };
```

If you wanted to get multiple statuses (i.e. hash key), you can use `batchGetItem` API. However, `batchGetItem` doesn't support index. You can use this API on main table only.

Comment: I tried it, but getting this error "message": "Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: IN",
    "code": "ValidationException"

Comment: Sorry, in KeyConditionExpression only equality operator can be used. IN can be used on Filter Expression.